# Root access for Jupyter/iPython Notebook

Tags: bash, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the bash kernel in iPython/Jupyter notebook, but I need sudo access within the notebook itself.

I've tried `$ sudo jupyter notebook` to run the notebook as root, but that only returns:

```
$ jupyter: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command
```

So, I'm left with running `$ jupyter notebook` (unless there's a way to run Jupyter notebook as root).

I also can't do `su root` in the notebook itself because that requires an input and the notebook won't let me give an input.

Finally, there is allegedly an `--allow-root` option for Jupyter notebook:
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

However, it looks like `--allow_root` is no longer an option. (I've tried modifying the config file by adding `NotebookApp.allow_root=True`, but that doesn't work.)

Any ideas guys? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: am having same issue here. cannot use snap.py in jupyter notebook

Comment: Still awaiting a solution...?

Answer (score 19):

Just login as root, then do the following command to start the notebook :

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

Answer (score 12):

The solution as described [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/524). Is to use

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" jupyter notebook
```

Basically the binary to call `jupyter notebook` is in the user's `PATH` variable, but not for root.

Best regards.

Comment: *****This is the true solution to this problem!!

Answer (score 9):

Add `c.NotebookApp.allow_root=True` from the root configuration files. That you don't need ask to `allow-root`every time then you start the notebook.

Edit:

Before edit the configuration file you need to run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` as root to make the file.

Comment: And where is this config file..?

Comment: Aetos the config file is generat affter comand: `$sudo jupyter notebook --generate-config` or `jupyter notebook --generate-config` as root, will return the local file.

Answer (score 2):

## Generate config

root@user# jupyter notebook --generate-config

> root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
> root@user# cd .jupyter/
> root@user:/.jupyter/# gedit jupyter_notebook_config.py
> Add line in jupyter_notebook_config.py

c.NotebookApp.allow_root=True

Comment: Can you explain your solution further?

Comment: In PyCharm with WSL, this solution works the best.

Answer (score 1):

I am running the neopixel library from a jupyter notebook.

The only thing that worked for me was first running the "sudo su" command to move into the root environment and then run "jupyter notebook" (--allow-root alone didn't work for me).

Answer (score 0):

You should try running the command     sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root        , I'm not sure why but this works. On the server it'll ask you for a password, if you have set up a password for it just type it in the box that will be shown, otherwise, type      jupyter notebook password          to set up a new password

Answer (score 0):

When I need to execute command as root in my notebook, I use the `-A` flag, that allows to access an helper program used to read the user's password when no terminal is available.
You need to modify the `sudo.conf` file before to declare the helper program. On a Debian Buster, I personnaly added:

**Path askpass**: `/usr/libexec/seahorse/ssh-askpass`

See the main page of `sudo.conf` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo ~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook --allow-root
```

Switching user using su didn't work because I didn't have jupyter installed on root. Using just --allow-root by itself also didn't work for me. This allows you to run sudo with jupyter notebook without running into the issue of "notebook" not being a valid command. Because I am using a linux terminal, jupyter-notebook is installed at ~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook. See [After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found) for more information about where jupyter may be installed.